# How can my search form submit to a URL without a ? in the middle?

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-routing

I want to create a search form.

When I enter my query and press the submit button, I want submit to a URL - `domain.com/query/there_is_my_query`, but how to make this?

If I change method to GET, that URL will be `domain.com/query/?query=there_is_my_query`.

But if I change action to `/query/`, then In controller put `$_POST['search']`, that URL will be `domain.com/query`.

**Edit!**

I thought and decided to leave the following url - `domain.com/query/?search=there_is_my_query`.

Comment: is this, so that you can have beautiful URL that direct to search result?

Comment: you should have to use `.htaccess` to make seo friendly url

Comment: As far as I understood his problem was creating the request, not handling it.

Comment: Not sure what this answer has to do with the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To let you know, search engines do not use search forms.
So there is no point in making them search engine friendly.

Answer (score 0):

You can either modify your `index.php` to redirect any request containing `$_GET['query']` via redirect like this:

```
header('Location: http://domain.com/query/' . urlencode($_GET['query']));
```

Or otherwise you need to use JavaScript to create the new URL once the user clicks the submit button. Neither solution seems overly reasonable, if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

The following will work, however it is considered bad practice to use global arrays in Kohana:

```
Route::set('query', function ($uri)
        {
            $query_string = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
            if (preg_match('/query=(.+)/', $query_string, $matches))
            {
                return array(
                    'controller' => 'index',
                    'action' => 'query',
                    'id' => $matches[1],
                );
            }
        }, '(<action>(/<id>))');
```

The problem is that Kohana's routing system is not designed to work with the query string. If you really need to go this this way, then you'll have to move the logic out of Kohana into the .htaccess file, using mod_rewrite.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the Apache `rewrite` module for redirect the requests to a point (bootstrap). This bootstrap will parse the URLs and it will get the params.